# Swift 3 app runs on simulator crashes on device

Tags: ios, asynchronous, ios-simulator, swift3, alamofire

I use Alamofire library for my requests. When I run the app on the simulator it works fine, but when I run it on a real device it crashes.

The following code makes the app to crashes:

```
downloadSubviewColumn(selectedMaster: selectedMaster,subviewNumber: subviewNumber){(value) -> Void in
            if !value.isEmpty{
                let seperatedColumn = value.components(separatedBy: "^")
                var paramsString = ""
                for i in seperatedColumn {
                    paramsString.append(";\(i)~\(self.dataArray[indexPath.row][Int(i)!])")
                }
                paramsString.remove(at: paramsString.startIndex)
                self.downloadSubviewData(selectedMaster: self.selectedMaster , params:paramsString ,subviewNumber: self.subviewNumber){(value) -> Void in
                    if !value.isEmpty{
                        self.headerArray.removeAll()
                        self.dataArray.removeAll()
                        self.tableViewDetail.reloadData()
                        let arraySeperatedBySpace = value.components(separatedBy: "\r")
                        let arraySeperatedByPercent = arraySeperatedBySpace.filter({$0.characters.first == "%"})
                        self.footerSettings = arraySeperatedByPercent[0].replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "")
                        self.headerArray = self.setHeader(arraySeperatedBySpace: arraySeperatedBySpace)
                        self.dataArray = self.setData(arraySeperatedBySpace: arraySeperatedBySpace , headerArray: self.headerArray)

                        self.setTableWidth()
                        self.tableViewDetail.reloadData()
                        self.subviewNumber += 1


                    }else{
                        self.alert(message: "Veri Bulunamadı.", title: "title")
                    }
                }
            }else{
                self.alert(message: "Altveri Bulunamadı.", title: "title")
            }
}
```

Here is `downloadSubviewColumn()`:

```
func downloadSubviewColumn(selectedMaster : String,subviewNumber : Int ,subdataCompletionHandler : @escaping CompletionHandler){

var subviewNumberString = ""
    if subviewNumber < 10{
        subviewNumberString = "00\(subviewNumber)"
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let url = "my_url".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
        Alamofire.request(url).responseString(completionHandler: { response in
            switch response.result{
            case .failure(_):
                subdataCompletionHandler("")
                SwiftSpinner.hide()
            case .success(_):
                guard let tempData = response.data , let detailResponse = String(data: tempData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    return
                }
                if !detailResponse.isEmpty{
                    subdataCompletionHandler(detailResponse)
                    SwiftSpinner.hide()

                }else{
                    subdataCompletionHandler("")
                    SwiftSpinner.hide()
                }
            }
        })
        // Go back to the main thread to update the UI
        DispatchQueue.main.async {


        }
}
}
```

And here is `downloadSubviewData()`:

```
func downloadSubviewData(selectedMaster : String ,params : String , subviewNumber : Int,subdataCompletionHandler : @escaping CompletionHandler){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        var subviewString = ""
        if subviewNumber < 10{
            subviewString = "00\(subviewNumber)"
        }else{
            subviewString = "0\(subviewNumber)"
        }
        let url = "my_url2".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
        print(url)
        Alamofire.request(url).responseString(completionHandler: { response in
            switch response.result{
            case .failure(_):
                subdataCompletionHandler("")
                SwiftSpinner.hide()
            case .success(_):
                guard let tempData = response.data , let detailResponse = String(data: tempData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    return
                }
                print(detailResponse)
                if !detailResponse.isEmpty{
                    subdataCompletionHandler(detailResponse)
                    SwiftSpinner.hide()

                }else{
                    subdataCompletionHandler("")
                    SwiftSpinner.hide()
                }
            }
        })
        // Go back to the main thread to update the UI
        DispatchQueue.main.async {


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the log you get on the console when the app is running on your device?

Comment: add exceptional break point. so you can see where exactly its crashing.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/phZRygF8

Comment: @Ashok I tried but it crashes at the same point,see error log I put at pastebin.